# Need help locating SSH access on cPanel

Tags: networking, command-line, ssh, cpanel

I have cpanel 78.0.41, looking up online I've been told that it is in Security/SSH Access or Advanced/SSH Access but I can't locate it anywhere.

I also tried to locate the terminal but I can't see it anywhere

Some screenshots.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, you don't have it.

Here it is in my cPanel, in the Security section:

[image: cPanel screen shot]

Some hosts do not allow SSH access. Others will only enable it once you convince them you need it. A few, limited, have some of the controls outside cPanel using their own custom versions. Your cPanel looks full, so I doubt that it your case.

You can contact your hoster's support service and ask if SSH is possible.

SSH access is now one of my top question before signing with a host (unless the client has already signed one before I came on board).